# Rewrite query string with another get params

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a link like this:

```
/catalog/section/?PAGEN_1=1&search=someWord

/news/?PAGEN_1=2
```

where PAGEN_1=(page number)

I try to set URL to:

```
/catalog/section/?page=1&search=someWord

/news/?page=2
```

But this not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)PAGEN_1=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1?page=%1 [L,R]
```

I need to save another GET params.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule to rename a query parameter from `PAGEN_1` to `page`:

```bash
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?PAGEN_1=([^&]*)(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1page=%2%3 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your `mod_rewrite` rules.